# Android defaultSensor TYPE_SIGNIFICANT_MOTION returns null after 24 hours

Tags: android, activity-recognition, activitytransitionapi, significant-motion-sensor

I'm little bit confused why my `Transitions API` solution works usually for first day or two and after that stop receiving any updates. I dug deeper into it and found a lead that talks about how we need to have `SIGNIFICAT_MOTION` sensor active in order to wake up sensors that eventually wake up `Transitions API` solution as a whole.

What I did was I implemented listener that helps me understand when `SIGNIFICANT_MOTION` sensor is enabled and when not:

```
    try {
        boolean request = sensorManager.requestTriggerSensor(triggerEventListener, sensor);
        Timber.e("Transitions API is working. If returns false - device is STILL");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException exception) {
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_SIGNIFICANT_MOTION);

        Timber.e("SensorManager - " + sensorManager + ", sensor - " + sensor); //TODO: Later delete
    }
```

Now as you can see, whenever this code throws exception I try to re-initialize sensors to make sure exception is not thrown later in the app. Logs show that `sensor is null`.

When sensor turns to null after day or two (for first day it works well and device returns sensor value correctly), there's no way to fix the issue anymore except rebooting the device.

**Question:** Why does `sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_SIGNIFICANT_MOTION);` return value (sensor) for first day, but after 48ish hours returns null and stops working? (I believe that messes up my Transitions API solution and is root cause of why it is not working).

Additional information.

Phone: Google Pixel 3A
OS: Android 12

I think this ticker might be related? https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/259298110

Comment: Could you give some more context of how you use this sensor? It might not be the correct one for your use case.  I never worked with this API but check this out https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor#TYPE_SIGNIFICANT_MOTION it says that it disables itself after it fires an event once. "It triggers when an event occurs and then automatically disables itself." so it actually sounds like this is the desired behavior for this type of sensor and this would make some sense why you need to reboot the device to make it work again.

Comment: @RaduM Don't think that applies to my case - I know that it fires 1 time, so instead, when it fires, I reset the listener so I can actively listen for changes. Logs also prove that this works multiple times in the first day, but then suddenly stops together with logging null for sensor - which is weird and feels like a different issue.

Comment: Ok no clue then but did you try with a different device and see if you can reproduce it? I mean it could be a hardware issue maybe? The Android Keystore is at least a story of itself too